# How to include assets in a library project created with the Angular CLI?

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I am developing a library using Angular CLI. In a **normal project** you have an `assets` directory where include *images*, *svg* and other files that will be distributed for production in `dist` folder. How can I include assets files for distribution in a **library project** created with the CLI? Thanks.

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/11071

Comment: @kunwar97 Thanks for the url, it has been very useful. I managed to include assets in my library project. See my other comment below.

Answer (score 1):

I use npm install lifecycle hooks. created a `postinstall.js` containing the copy command for pasting it the directory where I want these assets to be placed in the angular application when someone installs my lib.

You also need to modify the np-packgr configuration  `"keepLifecycleScripts": true`

```
"scripts": {
        "postinstall": "node post-install.js"
    },
    "peerDependencies": {},
    "ngPackage": {
        "$schema": "../node_modules/ng-packagr/ng-package.schema.json",
        "dest": "../../../../dist",
        "workingDirectory": ".ng_build",
        "lib": {
            "entryFile": "./index.ts",
            "externals": {}
        },
        "keepLifecycleScripts": true
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. I managed to add statics assets to my angular library proyect this way: 1) Install cpx package: `npm install cpx --save-dev`
2) In your package.json add the following:

    `"scripts": 
    {
         "copy-lib-assets": "cpx ./src/assets/**/* ./dist/angular-jwt-auth/assets",
         "build-lib-with-assets": "ng build my_library && npm run copy-lib-assets"
    }` Sorry I can't add comments

Comment: Yes... this is half part. May be want to put library assest to application assets dir at the time of installtion. So to do that you also need to put the  install script which does the copy paste from node_modules to app assets dir

Comment: Your are right. I didn't think on that. It's more complicated than it seems at first sight. It's a pitty neither angular-cli nor ng-packgr take that in account. I'll try your method. Thanks again.

Comment: I also thinking of this because I have many libs and apps in `Nx Workspace` project setup. But still not got the standard way of pushing assets from libs to app in that setup. So I am doing some manual work there.